# Postgresql mulit-column join containing NULL values

Tags: postgresql

I would like to `JOIN` two tables in Postgresql 9.5 `ON` two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 TEXT);
CREATE TABLE table_b (col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 TEXT);

INSERT INTO table_a (col1, col2, col3)
  VALUES (1, 2, 'foo'), (NULL, 3, 'foo');

INSERT INTO table_b (col1, col2, col3)
  VALUES (1, 2, 'bar'), (NULL, 3, 'bar');
```

When I do the join

```
SELECT a.col3, b.col3
FROM table_a a
  LEFT JOIN table_b b
    ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND
       a.col2 = b.col2;
```

the row with the `null` value is not joined.

```
a.col3 | b.col3
---------------
  foo  |  bar
  foo  | <null>
```

However, I would like to have both columns joined, i.e. including the ones where one of the values is null. So there should be foo bar appearing twice in this example. How could I make this work?

Comment: something like `ON coalesce(a.col1,-1) = coalesce(b.col1,-1) AND a.col2 = b.col2`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Totally works. Nice. Care for an accepted answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have values that do not occur in that column, you could use `coalesce()` for this:

```
SELECT a.col3, b.col3
FROM table_a a
  LEFT JOIN table_b b
    ON ON coalesce(a.col1,-1) = coalesce(b.col1,-1) AND a.col2 = b.col2
```

Note that this will **only** work if you do **not** have any (real) rows with `col1 = -1` otherwise you'll get a wrong result!